# Chart.js Bar chart doesn't show bars for multiple items

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I am using chart.js with asp.net mvc 5 c# to draw charts. I am now facing a problem where multiple data values don't show the bar charts but only display the names. So for example    data: [results.AppsName] can be "MoreTesting,Search,Test_email" if data: [results.AppsName] is for example "MoreTesting", the chart displays correctly. Below is a portion of my code.

```js
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
 
 success: function (results) {
                
                if (results !== null) {
                    
                    var barChartData =
                    {
                        labels: [results.Apps], 
                        datasets: [{
                                label: 'Apps Count',
                                backgroundColor: [
                                    "#f990a7",
                                    "#aad2ed",
                                    "#9966FF",
                                    "#99e5e5",
                                    "#f7bd83"
                                ],
                            borderWidth: 2,
                               
                            data: [results.AppsName] //This portion can have multiple values like "MoreTesting,Search,Test_email" or a single value like "MoreTesting"
                            }
                        ]
                    };
                   
                    var ctx1 = document.getElementById("barcanvas").getContext("2d");
                    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx1, {
                        type: 'bar',
                        data: barChartData,
                        options:
                        {
                            title:
                            {
                                display: true,
                                text: "Apps Count"
                            },
                            responsive: true,
                            maintainAspectRatio: true
                        }
                         
                     });
                }
                   
            }

        });
```

Comment: Can you share sample data/response for `results.AppsName`? Thanks.

Comment: ( data: [results.AppsName]) sample data/response = MoreTesting,Search,Test_email and for labels: [results.Apps] sample data/response 2,1,9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the additional brackets (`[]`) for `results.Apps` and `results.AppsName`.

As your current code, it will categorize all the labels as a category, but not multiple categories (bar).

```js
  var barChartData = {
    labels: results.Apps,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Apps Count',
        backgroundColor: [
          '#f990a7',
          '#aad2ed',
          '#9966FF',
          '#99e5e5',
          '#f7bd83',
        ],
        borderWidth: 2,

        data: results.AppsName,
      },
    ],
  };
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-wp8pm9?file=index.html)

Comment: I have done exactly as you have done but I am getting  Unhandled exception at line 14, column 16002 in http://localhost:1960/Scripts/DashboardJS/Chart.bundle.min.js
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'map' occurred

Comment: Sound weird, can youu confirm that your response is in this format? `{ Apps: ['MoreTesting', 'Search', 'Test_email'], AppsName: [10] }`

Comment: I have just make sure that the format is in array form like this { Apps: ['MoreTesting', 'Search', 'Test_email'], AppsName: [10] } so I don't get the 'map' error any more but the bar charts anot not showing

Comment: Hmmm, good one, getting closer to the answer. It's hard to know the actual error. I assume that you received the response correctly. Does your canvas element exist, and etc. Maybe need your side to debug and let us know in more context. Thanks.

Comment: I got it working thanks a lot. I changed  this part of my code from .ToList() to      var appCount = (from temp in AppCounts
                                select temp.AppNames).ToArray(); and the charts are showing up now

Comment: So calling .ToList() was the issue in addition didn't need the [] like you said